# how to get minutes from 2019-03-10 09:39:57 +0900 date in jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to get only minutes from `2019-05-07 13:05:08 +0900` 
I added this field as a  `java.sql.Timestamp`

I have tried with--
`java.util.Date`
`java.sql.Date`

Comment: In Java `OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-05-07 13:05:08 +0900", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss XX")).getMinute()` (yields 5).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp`, `java.util.Date` nor `java.sql.Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern option in date fields. The syntax works like java, by setting the format to "dd.mm.yyyy" and so on.
EDIT: There is an example [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/510239/date-format-ddmmyyyy) how to change the pattern to `dd/mm/yyyy`:

> For this porpouse, use the pattern field of your textfield. Set the class of the field to `java.util.Date` and insert in the pattern field the string `mm/dd/yyyy (or dd/mm/yyyy)`

You can edit your pattern accordingly for just getting minutes.

As I do not have iReport installed currently I can only offer a solution on sql level: You also could format the selected field in your sql code:

`select 
sys_extract_utc(current_timestamp) as sql_timestamp,
to_char(sys_extract_utc(current_timestamp), 'MI') as timestamp_minutes,
to_char(sys_extract_utc(current_timestamp), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as datetime_character
from dual;`

This results in 

`SQL_TIMESTAMP               | TIMESTAMP_MINUTES | DATETIME_CHARACTER
17.05.19 10:56:42,567411000 | 56                | 17-MAI-2019 10:56:42`

But please be adviced that the last suggestion results in selecting characters rather than timestamps.

If you have more questions, feel free to ask.